# How to create big data project?

Tags: java, bigdata

Anyone please guide me to create a big data project in java and what are the tools and technologies need to develop.

1. Hadoop
2. mogoDB
3. NoSQL

In above mentioned which technology is using to develop the big data concept in Java.

Comment: What in particular are you asking?  Hadoop is written in Java if that is what you are asking.  MongoDB in C/C++, and NoSQL is a broad term.

Comment: You'll need to narrow down your query. Are you asking difference b/w these 3?

Comment: No,but can you  please tell me how to create a project in big data using java with monoDB

Answer (score 2):

This question is very broad; big data "Projects" can range from writing MapReduce jobs, to using frameworks like Spring XD to automate the import of data into your environment, to using tools like GraphX visualization and MLLib machine learning libraries to analyze the data you have.  The first step towards starting your project would be to figure out what you or your organization want to accomplish.

Since your question seems to at least in part be asking about what technologies to familiarize yourself with, I would suggest looking towards getting a Cloudera or Hortonworks VM to stand up and play with an environment, since those environments come with a complete suite of Big Data tools for you to work with and develop for, and are the easiest way to get started with figuring out what you can do.  Once you have a better idea of your organizations goals or your own interests, more specific internet searches will lead you to books, tools, and tutorials to do what you want to do.